# How to Style First Column Only In a Dynamic Bootstrap Row

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, opencart

I am Designing a Shopping Cart based on Opencart. Following is the main part of code in  Category.tpl file that products are updating from

```
  <div class="row">
    <?php foreach ($products as $product) { ?>
    <div class="product-layout product-list col-xs-12">
      <div class="product-thumb">

        <div class="image"><a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $product['thumb']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" title="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" class="img-responsive" /></a> </div>
        <div>
```

And Below is the css it is generating

```
<div class="row">
              <div class="product-layout product-grid col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                 <div class="product-thumb">

             <div class="image"><a href="http://rangawoods.tryfcomet.com/index.php?route=product/product&amp;path=78&amp;product_id=194"><img src="http://rrrwoods.com/image/cache/catalog/Door/SMD-001-500x500.jpg" alt="SMD-001" title="SMD-001" class="img-responsive"></a> </div>


        <div>
```

Now I need to Style the First Column only in created row.How can I do this? I have attached an Image for quick ref.

[image]

Comment: show us your code

Comment: can you please add some  code

Comment: can u show html??

Comment: that is not "the css it is generating" - there's no css there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
.row div[class^="col"]:first-child {
    border: 3px solid black;
}
```

Example

```css
.row div[class^="col"]:first-child {
    border: 3px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    one
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    two
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    Three
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    Four
  </div>
</div>
```

**Update:** with your rendered html I think its not possible, you have all the col inside a row. In Bootstrap prespective it will work, but you cannot target all the 1st element what the user sees in the page, because it differ with screen resolution.

[image]

If you need to just style the first col, you can use this code

```
.row .product-layout:first-child {
    border: 3px solid red;
}
```

[image]

Comment: it would actually be pretty easy to target the first item in each row since the bootstrap framework is going to break them at known intervals base on the row classes `col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12`.  you just need to set nth-child styles in media queries to correspond with where the breakpoints are set

Answer (score 0):

You should try first child class for creating border, Ex

```
.row .col-lg-3:first-child{
    border:1px solid red;
}
```