# CSS/HTML how to show only the first two lines of a flexbox

Tags: javascript, html, css

For a project I need to create a search bar. The search results need to be displayed in a grid. The items should be next to each other and two rows high. If there are more results I need to show a button `+32` to display all the results.

The problem I am facing is that I have no idea how to accomplish this. I have used flexbox and flex-wrap in order to get new items to be shown in the next line when they don't fit on the previous one. But I don't know how to only display the first two lines.

[image]

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: blue;
  max-width: 15rem;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.item{
  background-color: red;
  padding: 0 0.2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <p>Hello</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>Helllooo</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>Hel</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>Hello</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>Test</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>For</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>Hello</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>Hello</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>Helllooo</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>Hel</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>Hello</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: set the height to be equal to 2*height of one line

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50253626/how-to-style-first-column-only-in-a-dynamic-bootstrap-row

Comment: @TemaniAfif This will make all the exces items be shown outside the container.

Comment: You should be able to do this relatively easily with some JS magic

Comment: overflow:hidden to hide them

Comment: @knosmos something in the lines of: Making the sum of each child's width and all the previous childeren. Then only showing those childeren that have a total width sum that is smaller than the width*2 of the container.

Comment: @TemaniAfif This works. But it doesn't allow me to add the `+32` button at the end of the second row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a quick solution, although it doesn't calculate the length yet.

```js
items = ["Helooo","Testing","Holaaaa","Hiiii","Hello","Greetings fine sir","Welcome","Bonjour","Oi you there"];

let limit = 5; // You will need to calculate this somehow

function display(limit){
    document.getElementById("searchContainer").innerHTML = "";
    for (let item of items.slice(0,limit)){
        document.getElementById("searchContainer").innerHTML += `<div class=item>${item}</div>`;
    }
    if (items.length > limit){
        document.getElementById("searchContainer").innerHTML += `<div class=item onclick="display(${items.length})">+${items.length-limit}</div>`;
    }
}

display(limit);
```

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  max-width: 15rem;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.item{
  background-color: rgb(100,100,200);
  padding: 0 0.2rem;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class=container id=searchContainer>
</div>
```